# Python: 'as' keyword in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, keyword

I know this won't work but you guys get the idea.

```
c = [m.split('=')[1] as a for m in matches if a != '1' ]
```

Is there a way to archive this? If you use a list comprehension like

```
c = [m.split('=')[1] as a for m in matches if m.split('=')[1] != '1' ]
```

two lists will be build from the `split`, right?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that in a single list comprehension in general.  (You can iterate over a preprocessed version of the list, but you can't "save" the target expression that way.)

Comment: Too bad...Also in python 3x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use use a generator expression inside the list comprehension:

```
c = [a for a in (m.split('=')[1] for m in matches) if a != '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

It's sorta-possible, but when you find yourself resorting to awful hacks like the following, it's time to use a regular loop:

```
c = [a for m in matches for a in [m.split('=')[1]] if a != '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it, and there's no real point in using a nested `map` or nested list comprehension as the other solutions show.  If you want to preprocess the list, just do:

```
whatIwant = (m.split('=')[1] for m in matches)
c = [a for a in whatIwant if a != 1]
```

Using a nested list comp or `map` saves nothing, since the entire list is still processed.  All it does is reduce readability.

Comment: But imap wont preprocess the entire list.

Comment: @perreal: It won't *pre*-process it, but it will still process all of it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
c = [ a for a, m in map(lambda x: (x.split('=')[1], x), matches) if a != '1' ]
```

you may want to use `imap` instead of `map`. Some cleaner version:

```
def right_eq(x): return (x.split('=')[1], x)

c = [ a for a, m in imap(right_eq, matches) if a != '1' ]
```

Comment: For reasons of readability I'd go for a normal for loop. But nice solution!